# Dealing with WhiteSpaces while accessing Structure "keys"

Tags: coldfusion

Please consider the following image: [image]

So, How do I correctly access "Android Phone" key in the structure. When I do the following(An excerpt from my code):

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen#" index="i">


        <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
        <cfoutput>#cfData[i].open.AOL#</cfoutput>

      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

    </cfloop>
```

It works fine, however, when I try to `<cfoutput>` it like the following :

```
<cfoutput>#cfData[i].open.Android Phone#</cfoutput>
```

OR

```
<cfoutput>#cfData[i].open.AndroidPhone#</cfoutput>
```

I get the following error:

Element OPEN.ANDROIDPHONE is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

The error occurred in C:myfile.cfm: line 185

```
183 :         <!--- <cfloop list="#KeyList#" index="colItem"> --->    
184 :         <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
185 :         <cfoutput>#cfData[i].open.AndroidPhone#</cfoutput>
186 :         
187 :       <cfelse>
```

**Question #2: I am encountering one more weird phenomenon:**

When I am outputtin the values like the following:

```
<cfoutput>#cfData[i]["open"]["Android Phone"]#</cfoutput>
```

and

```
 <cfoutput>#cfData[i]["open"]["Android Tablet"]#</cfoutput>
```

It works perfectly fine.

However, when I change it to following:

```
<cfoutput>#cfData[i]["open"]["Lotus Notes"]#</cfoutput>
```

I am getting the following error:

Element Lotus Notes is undefined in a CFML structure referenced as part of an expression.

```
The error occurred in C:myfile.cfm: line 185

183 :             
184 :         <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
185 :         <cfoutput>#cfData[i]["open"]["Lotus Notes"]#</cfoutput>
186 :         
187 :       <cfelse>
```

Is it like it only works for a series of space related keys and not for the one which occur after single words keys? Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case because of the space you can't use the dot notation so you must use the bracket-quote notation:

```
<cfoutput>#cfData[i]["open"]["Android Phone"]#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Dot notation can make for easier-to-read code, when you are in control of the variable names.

Comment: (From deleted answer): FYI, In order to use dot notation, the key name must be a [valid variable name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fd3.html).

Comment: @Leigh Thanks. Could you please check my Question #2? Thanks

Comment: Then the structure you are using does not contain that *exact* key (even white space makes a difference). Are you absolutely certain "Lotus Notes" exists in every element - or are just assuming it does? Add some debugging code just before the line that errors and see what keys are available. ie `#StructKeyList(cfData[i].open)#`.

Comment: Nope, "Lotus Notes" does not exists in every element.For some structures it will exist and for some it won't. If that's the case, I was thinking that `<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>` would have been taking care of the missing key.

Comment: Adding your debugging code produced following results: `Thunderbird,BlackBerry,Apple Mail,Other,iPod,Android Phone,Windows Live Mail,Other Webmail,Postbox,Hotmail,Sparrow,iPhone,Outlook,Android Tablet,iPad,AOL,Lotus Notes,Gmail,Eudora,Yahoo `

Comment: *would have been taking care of the missing key.* Nope. You are only verifying `cfData[i]` contains a key named "open". You have to check the "open" structure keys separately.

Comment: @Leigh By saying checking "open" structure keys separately , I don't think I can use something like the following:`<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open.Lotus Notes")>` . Did you mean some different approach to check the keys separately?

Comment: @user3239126 - StructureKeyExists does not support dot-notation for key names. So the exact syntax depends on whether the parent key always exists. If not, you need to do two checks: one for the parent key and one for the child key ie `<cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open") AND structKeyExists(cfData[i]["open"], "Lotus Notes")> do something...</cfif>`.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks. Your suggested check worked. I didn't know that we can use AND and another structkeyexists to check further more.